# Appengine taskqueues to cloud tasks migration

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-tasks

I am migrating some Appengine taskqueues to use the Cloud Tasks API.

Many things are different and among them is the `eta` and `countdown` in taskqueues vs `scheduled_time` in Cloud Tasks. As I understand, one can only use `scheduled_time` instead of `eta` on a task, and for `countdown` one has to implements ones own `countdown` to `scheduled_time` converter. Is this true or is there another "google-native" way to port the countdown feature that I am missing?

Relevant docs:

A Cloud Task [Task](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.tasks.v2#task)
A Cloud Task [CreateTaskRequest](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.tasks.v2#createtaskrequest)
Appengine [taskqueue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.taskqueue.taskqueue#google.appengine.api.taskqueue.taskqueue.Task) (please search for "countdown")

Comment: I think the only way as far as I have searched it is to implement your own countdown and link it to schedule_time.